# Showing that $(a_n)_n \in l_1$ provided $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_kx_k$ exists for any $(x_n)_n \in c_0$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, absolute-convergence

I tried first using the fact that $c_0$ is Banach to apply the Uniform Boundedness Principle on the function series $(T_n)_n = \{\sum_{k=1}^n a_kx_k\}$, $T_n:c_0 \rightarrow \mathbb{K}$, and then to extend that results to a series of functionals $T_n:l_\infty \rightarrow \mathbb{K}$ using Hahn-Banach theorem,
but that way I can't get absolute convergence of (a_n)_n, only "normal" convergence, which is not enough for $(a_n)_n \in l_1$.

Perhaps there's a better way?

Comment: What did you find for the value of $||T_n||$?

Comment: I can tell that $||T_n||$ are mutually bounded using the uniform boundedness principle

Comment: That wasn't the question. What _is_ $||T_n||$? It's not hard to calculate $||T_n||$ exactly; once you know what $||T_n||$ actually _is_ then the Uniform Boundeness Principle gives you exactly what you want...

Comment: UB is overkill. If $(a_n)\notin\ell_1$, you can choose $n_1< n_2< \cdots$ with $\sum_{i=n_k}^{n_{k+1}-1} |a_i|>1$ for each $k$. With this, it's not hard to find $(x_n)\in c_0$ with $\sum a_i x_i=\infty$.

Comment: @DavidMitra Well of course. And  I actually prefer what you suggest. But I conjecture that UB was given as a hint - could even be that the actual exercise said "show how this follows from UB". (In fact when I assigned exactly this problem last year I specified I wanted _two_ solutions...)